# WebBeans context with scope type annotation @SessionScoped does not exist within current thread

Tags: cdi, session-scope

I have a bean that does some logic, I call it logicBean,
and it has a sessionscoped bean as field with @Inject.

I use this logicbean in two situations in one JAVA EE6 Application,
1. in servlet.
2. in message driven bean.

In the second situcation, I got a excetion
"WebBeans context with scope type annotation @SessionScoped does not exist within current thread".
I know there is no sessionScope in MDB, so I made another bean, and want to
inject it to logicBean dynamicly to alternative the sessionScoped bean.

I do not know how to do this.
please help me, thanks.

Comment: But you're still keeping the session scoped bean?

Comment: what I want is, 1. in servlet, the logicBean uses Sessionscoped bean, 2. in MDB, the logicBean uses another bean. How can I tell CDI when to inject the Sessionscoped bean and  when to inject another bean. thanks

Comment: In that case, your best bet is to keep scoped out of the bean definition and use producers and qualifiers.

Comment: I am going to Inject the Bean by qualifier outside the LogicBean,and set it in to LogicBean.seams it the only way. thank you very much.